# Embedding Mapbox map into wordpress web page?

Tags: mapbox, tilemill, wordpress

I want to embed a mapbox map into my wordpress web page.

I did the map with tilemill and saved into mapbox but I don't know how I would embed the map in wordpress.

Comment: -1 did not conduct any research before posting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://learnosm.org/en/map-design/mapbox/ <- quick google search.

> ADDING THE MAP TO YOUR SITE
>
> To embed the map in your website, you can get an embeddable link by
>   clicking on “Embed.” When you copy and paste the html into your
>   website, the map you have saved here will be shown in a window on your
>   site. If you have a website built on a common CMS, there may be a
>   MapBox plugin that will easily allow you to add maps to your site.
>
> MapBox on WordPress
>
> Putting your map into your website is easy with Wordpress. Simply find
>   the MapBox plugin and install it. The plugin can be found at
>   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mapbox/.
>
> wordpress plugin
>
> This plugin will allow you to copy the embedding html into WordPress
>   and allow you to easily add maps to your posts.